# Perl string replace not working with $1 and $2

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Search and replace is not working when I use $1 and $2 defined earlier.

It works when I store it in a new variable.

Does not work as intended.

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   my $rep = "";
   my $orig = "";
   if ($name =~ /sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/) {
      $orig = $1;
      $rep = $2;
      $name =~ s/$1/$2/;
      print "$name\n";
   }
'
sta middle end
```

Is it because $1 and $2 are getting replaced in the new $name =~ I am doing?

Works as intended.

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   my $rep = "";
   my $orig = "";
   if ($name =~ /sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/) {
      $orig = $1;
      $rep = $2;
      $name =~ s/$orig/${rep}/;
      print "$name\n";
   }
'
staend middle end
```

Is there a better one liner to do this? I do not want to define new variables.

Answer (score 3):

The capture variables are reset by running the match in the first part of the s/// operator, for the replacement to use. The m// operator in list context will return the captured values so you can easily assign them there. Also you may want to use \Q ([quotemeta](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta)) if your search string is not a regex.

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   if (my ($orig, $rep) = $name =~ /sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/) {
      $name =~ s/\Q$orig/$rep/;
      print "$name\n";
   }
'
sta middle end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the new successful regex match replaces `$1` and `$2`.

You could avoid the global vars entirely as follows:

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   if ( my ($orig, $rep) = $name =~ /sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/ ) {
      $name =~ s/\Q$orig/$rep/;
      CORE::say $name;
   }
'
```

Better yet, you could avoid doing two matches as follows:

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   if ( $name =~ s/sta\K.*?(?=\s\w+\s(.*))/$1/ ) {
      CORE::say $name;
   }
'
```

However, I'd use the following:

```
perl -e'
   my $name = "start middle end";
   if ( (my ($prefix, $suffix, $foo) = $name =~ /^(.*?sta).*?(\s\w+\s(.*))/ ) {
      CORE::say "$prefix$foo$suffix";
   }
'
```

Note that your code suffered from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug which I fixed using `quotemeta` (as `\Q`).

Answer (score 1):

Here, just in case, we'd have had unexpected extra spaces, we could also try this expression:

```
(sta)([a-z]*)\s+(\w+)\s+(.+)
```

It's just another option.

#### TEST

```
perl -e'
    my $name = "start       middle    end";
    $name =~ s/(sta)([a-z]*)\s+(\w+)\s+(.+)/$1$4 $3 $4/;
    print "$name\n";
    '
```

#### OUTPUT

```
staend middle end
```

#### [Please see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/u7H36y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`$2` in the replacement part refers to the capture group from the pattern part of the same substitution. Therefore, you only need one variable to remember $2.

```
perl -lwe '$_ = "start middle end" ; if (/sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/) {my $rep = $2; s/$1/$rep/; print}'
staend middle end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid other variables by using the last match start and end global arrays `@-` and `@+` and just doing a substring replace:

```
my $name = "start middle end";
if ($name =~ /sta(.*?)\s\w+\s(.*)/) {
    substr($name, $-[1], $+[1]-$-[1], $2);
    print "$name\n";
}
```

See the entry for `@-` in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

The regex capture variables exhibit strange behavior depending on code
flow, function calls and other stuff.
To fully explain and wrap a head around this requires a few pages
of explanation.

As for now, avoid the whole mess and just use a single regex

```
 perl -e'
    my $name = "start middle end";
    $name =~ s/^(sta)(.*?)(\s\w+\s)(.*)/$1$4$3$4/;
    print "$name\n";
 '
```